# Admin Choose Store View Missing?

Tags: admin, store-view, products-management, category-tree

I have just noticed that in my 1.9.0.1 store, the drop down boxes for selecting store view at the top left of the category and product pages are missing.

I have had a look at my old 1.6.2.0 store which has them. Have they been removed in the later versions and I just haven't noticed until now, or should they be there and something has just gone wrong to not load them?

1.6.2.0 Store:
[image]

1.9.0.1 Store:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked in back-end if it is there or not?

Comment: No it's not there at all, for example on the category management page it should be - Add Root Category, Add Sub Category, then the choose store view box - but its not there.

Comment: check once... system->manage stores. If it is not there you create new store view from there.

Comment: Yes, that's there.

Comment: OK, so then the problem is you have multiple stores view present in manage stores , but they are not showing in options???

Comment: While checking can you see they are enabled or not??

Comment: There is only one store, but I need to access it's 'Default Store View', it is enabled. However it's not that it isn't appearing in the list, it is that the list itself isn't showing. Ill add images to show what I mean.

Comment: This is the default view what you are working currently. If you want to have more store view just create new store view with some name and see on category page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default store view in which you are currently working on. If you wish to have any other store view then just create one new store view in system->manage stores-> create stores view. Then you will see the list what you are looking for on the category page.

Comment: Of course it's that simple, just me being stupid then. The reason I wanted to access Default store view is because on my other store changing things in All store views didn't always update default store view, so I thought it may be the case with this new store. Thanks.

Comment: It's my pleasure.